# @fontface local file will not show on site

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to upload a local font face. I tried this below. I have downloaded the file and put in in a folder with the rest of my code. Every instruction I look at only tells me how to upload online sourced fonts like Google Fonts.

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'JandaManatee';
      src: url("C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf") format("ttf");
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: "JandaManatee", sans-serif;
    }
```

As well as this-

```
 @font-face {
          font-family: 'JandaManatee';
          src: local("C:/Users/Kascey.Malone/Documents/Websites/Midterm/fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf") format("ttf");
        }
        
        body {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: "JandaManatee", sans-serif;
        }
```

[image: This is how I have the folders set up.]

Edit: I have also tried 'fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf' with no resolve.

Comment: The slash `/` is inccorect for a local file. Local files on windows should use backslash: `url("C:\Users\Kascey.Malone\Documents\Websites\Midterm\fonts\JandaManateeSolid.ttf") format("ttf")`

Comment: That did not work. It is highlighting the slashes when I changed them and readed that this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Giving absolute paths will not work here. Give relative path with respect to the stylesheet.

Try this

```
src: url('fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf') format("truetype");
```

Comment: /fonts/JandaManateeSolid.tt/ , adding / before fonts. does it work?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Could it be because of the ttf format?

Comment: format("ttf") replace with format("truetype")

Comment: Still nothing. Does it matter where to file is located. It's in the folder with the html and css files.

Comment: Yeah it matters, can you check the network tab of the dev tools and check the status of the .ttf file

Comment: Status says failed. I'm going to try another font.

Comment: Try creating a codepen, so we can take a closer look